# Meaning of __in , __out, __in_opt

Tags: visual-c++, microsoft-sal

What is the meaning of these keywords used before variables in a
 function parameters?

- `__in`
- `__out`
- `__in_opt`

Comment: those aren't keywords, thats Microsoft's SAL annotation

Comment: thanks ,that's means it no substantial effect?

Comment: for the compiler no, for the coder it should help him/her use the API correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are some of the older decoration macro's from Microsoft's SAL Annotations ([the newer ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) now follow different casing, starting with a capital, like `_In_`, `_Out_`, `_In_opt_`). These have no real affect on compilation (under VS 2010 they aren't even expanded), they are there for inline API documentation.

1. `__in`: this parameter is an input to the function (read-only, caller initialized).
2. `__out`: this parameter contains output from the function when it returns (write-only, caller initialized).
3. `__in_opt`: a compound annotation formed from `_in` and `_opt`, `_opt` indications that the parameter is optional and can be set to a default value (generally `NULL`).

You can get the full explanation here of the older decorations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: it is very detailed thanks very very much. i have searched for a long time now i finally found the answer here.

Answer (score 8):

As answered by Nercolis, these are SAL annotation attributes. However, these aren't just *internal* or just for *API documentation*. The real purpose is for **Code Analysis**. When you build the project with [/analyze](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis) compiler option (Project Properties, Code Analysis -> General), these play important role in finding the coding issues.

For example, if a particular pointer argument says `__in` then it must not be passed a null pointer. The function will not check for null and may cause SEH. `__in_opt` argument may be null. When compiler finds some issue, it reports it as a warning. See [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/118018/elucidating-all-about-code-analysis-in-visual-c).